# Odd character being returned when parsing RSS feed descriptions

Tags: android, rss, sax

When parsing the `<description>` tags found in several RSS feeds, I'm noticing that if they end with `[...]`, the value being displayed in my list is just the close bracket character `]`.

Here is but one example:

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
Warmup 2 mins thoracic spine mob [...]
]]>
</description>
```

I've tried replacing the `[...]` with the following line of code but the only character being displayed is the close bracket.

```
currentArticle.content = chars.replaceAll("[...]", "");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive ran into the same issue before. This is what ive done that worked well

```
 text = string.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

Comment: I tried that and now I get a blank description. It may be how I have the method coded though...

Comment: Make sure you have [...] exaclty how it appears.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It worked after I restructured my `characters` method.